# Fetch a file from task in same Ansible playbook

Tags: automation, ansible, centos, rhel

How do I transfer a file I have created from a previous task in my Ansible playbook? Here is what I got so far:

```yaml
- name: Create Yum Report
  shell: |
     cd /tmp
     yum history info > $(hostname -s)_$(date "+%d-%m-%Y").txt
  register: after_pir

- name: Transfer PIR
  fetch:
     src: /tmp/{{ after_pir }}
     dest: /tmp/
```

However, I receive this error message when I run my playbook.

```yaml
TASK [Transfer PIR] ************************************************************************************************************
failed: [x.x.x.x] (item=after_pir) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "after_pir", "msg": "the remote file does not exist, not transferring, ignored"}
```

I have tried to run different fetch, synchronzie and pull methods but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: The file exists in my remote server. The task "Create Yum Report" is successful and I am able to view it in my /tmp directory

Comment: why do you think the filename you have dynamically created in a shell command would be available in `after_pir` variable. `after_pir` will just be holding the result of the shell task. id suggest setting a variable in ansible for the file name, then you can use that variable when writting the file and when fetching the file.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I apologise but I am new at ansible. I dont understand what you meant. Could you provide more information? That would help me tremendously. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that:

```yaml
    - name: Create Yum Report
      command: yum history info
      register: yum_report

    - name: Dump report on local disk for each host
      copy:
         content: "{{ yum_report.stdout }}"
         dest: "/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname_short }}-{{ '%d-%m-%Y' | strftime }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```